# python & MySQLdb TypeError('not all arguments converted during string formatting',)

Tags: python, mysql

I've been googling around and can't solve my problem.

I have many queries working in earlier parts of my code with arguments but in my earlier cases I had only been passing strings . I also know that my query does work because I have tried it in Sequel Pro.

Then it all falls over at this bit of code:

```
    CA = 'CA10'
    Rank = 5
    CreateTempTable2 = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BadTranscripts AS " + \ 
         "(SELECT DISTINCT Transcript FROM Exon_InDelCons X, Exons E2, EnsSequences G WHERE " + \
         "CA = %s AND (Type = 'inserted' OR Type = 'deleted') AND Length > 11 " + \
         "AND X.Transcript = E2.EnsTranscriptId AND E2.Rank < %s " + \
         "AND X.Exon = E2.EnsExonId AND E2.EnsParentId = G.GenomicEnsId)"
    args2 = CA, Rank
    try:
      cursor.execute(CreateTempTable2, args2)
      cursor.connection.autocommit(True)
    except Exception, e:
       print "Can't create Temp Table BadTranscripts", repr(e)
```

CA is a string and Rank is an integer.

When I run this code I get the error:

```
TypeError('not all arguments converted during string formatting',)
```

If it helps I'm running python2.7 and MySQL Server on a Mac OSX10.9.5
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Oops! I've discovered my problem was actually in a following query where I simply used the incorrect variable name! So there is no problem with the query above - it does work. Thanks to everyone who has responded!

Comment: I've solved my own problem - it was a typo on the next query not shown here.